# Setting max date in calenderView to a specific date

Tags: java, android

I have the following code

```
CalendarView cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

cal.setMaxDate();
cal.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

I'm not sure how to format a date to put in `setMaxDate`, it says it wants a long data type? How would I format 31/12/2016 for example?

Answer (score 0):

`setMaxDate` expects a number of milliseconds since the epoch (see [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#getMaxDate())).

One way to do it would be:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
Date maxDate = sdf.parse("2016-12-31");
cal.setMaxDate(maxDate.getTime());
```

Or you could use a Calendar (untested but probably more efficient):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.clear();
c.set(2016, Calendar.DECEMBER, 31);
cal.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```